# WinRt: How to add and remove links on RichEditBox?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, rtf, uwp

I spent some time on the questions: how to convert a selection in a RichEditBox into a hyperlink and how to remove this link again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. But there are some workarounds to consider:

```
public void InsertLink(RichEditBox control, string url) 
{
  //Check some conditions - else property assignment crashes
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) return; 
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Document.Selection.Text)) return; 
  control.Document.Selection.Link = "\"" + url + "\"";
}

public void RemoveLink(RichEditBox control) 
{
  //Can only set Link to empty string, if a link is assigned, 
  //else property assignment crashes
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Document.Selection.Link)) return; 
  control.Document.Selection.Link = "";
}
```